# Knowing research problems of any area

Tags: reference-request

I have just started studying complex analysis in several variables, and while studying i came to know some of the research problems to work on for my Phd. Is there any journal or paper which publishes research problems for any particular area, for example Several complex variables. And if there is any way to know the status of any research problem. If anyone can help me in any way.

Comment: I don't think there is a "status monitoring" for *any* research problem that you think of. But there is the mathematical subject classification (MSC) that you can [read](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_Subject_Classification) about and have a look at the [scheme](http://msc2010.org/Default.html). Your research topic must be something like 32-XX and you can look for mathematical papers in any MSC category on [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/).

Comment: @BISHD can u please explain what this MSC is?

Comment: and what does it mean by 32-XX

Comment: Just read the wikipedia article I've referenced. It is a classification of mathematical subjects in categories. Your category has the 'name' 32-XX (several complex variables and analytic spaces) and contains several subcategories like 32Cxx (analytic spaces).

Comment: thanks alot for the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSC is the key issue here. See detailed comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Naven, the best way to know if your intended research has been done by others is to make a "secrete" search on your own. What I mean by secrete here is do not share your unfinished problem to others in a way they can be smart to finish what you have started.
   For instance, my MSC supervisor received an unpublished paper from someone whom he was a peer reviewer of the paper. My supervisor was telling me about another problem that arouse in the guy's work, and that problem could let the paper not to be published. So we (I and my supervisor could work on that problem).
  Make a search as much as you can on your own!